# URI is not a valid URI

Tags: localization

I'm getting an interesting (new) error when adding (or editing) entries in Chinese. If the slug is in Chinese I now get the following error:

```
URI is not a valid URI
```

It's interesting because I wasn't experiencing that with Craft 2.2. It was allowing me to save entries with Chinese characters in the URI. After upgrading to Craft 2.3.2615 it looks like all Chinese language URIs are now disallowed?

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Part of the problem may be related to character encoding? 

In Craft 2.2.2589 for instance, I have a URI that looks like: 
http://cn.craft.dev/admin/entries/editorial/159-与狐共舞-悉尼的狐狸收容中心/zh. 

In Craft 2.3.2615, the same entry URI now looks like: http://cn.craft.dev/admin/entries/editorial/159-%E4%B8%8E%E7%8B%90%E5%85%B1%E8%88%9E-%E6%82%89%E5%B0%BC%E7%9A%84%E7%8B%90%E7%8B%B8%E6%94%B6%E5%AE%B9%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83/zh

Comment: Looks like this is an unintended side effect of Craft calling [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), which started happening in 2.3. We’re looking into it…

Comment: Per [Brad's answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5090/45), this was identified as a bug and fixed in a recent release. Closing this thread as a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Turns out this was a bug introduced in 2.3 and will be fixed in the next release.</del>

**Update:**

This was fixed in [Craft 2.3.2617](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2617).

Comment: You gain way too much reputation here for announcing new features and bug fixes! Upvoted anyways, because I simply love Craft and your support.

Comment: Haha... for these I never know whether to post as an answer or a comment. And if they end up being a bug whether to vote to close the original question.

Comment: I suppose if someone is still on an older build they could run across this and find it useful?

Comment: Yes definitely! I was just joking, Brad. I think it's better as an answer as you further gain reputation for the "acceptance" click! :D

Comment: @Brad Keep posting the resolution as an answer... it makes it easier to reference when we close a thread as a "bug report". :)