# URI is not a valid URI error after recent update

Tags: craft3, localization

Has this old issue recurred in a very recent update:
[URI is not a valid URI](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/uri-is-not-a-valid-uri)

Just a few weeks ago I imported Korean content using FeedMe just fine, I have a setting 'limitAutoSlugsToAscii' => false, also. All Korean content and URLs were correctly showing in Korean.

I have updated Craft several versions since.

I need to do a re-import, but Korean is now all in English, and I get errors in FeedMe:

```
KO Categories Feed: Node #30 - {"uri":["URI is not a valid URI"]} - Process.php: 460.
```

If I manually edit the entry and set the URL to say 무게_감지_센서, the Admin CO also shows the error:

```
URI is not a valid URI
```

Thanks

Comment: This was a Craft bug that has been fixed in 3.2.7: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#327---2019-07-25

Comment: I confirm this fixes it for me, so thats excellent thanks for a speedy bug fix!